# Intellij colors in String with MySQL commands

Tags: mysql, string, intellij-idea, colors

I have this code:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player_stats(uuid varchar(36) primary key, deaths int, kills int, block_broken long, balance double, last_login DATE, last_logout DATE)";
statement.execute(sql);
```

and I want to have the commands for the MySQL database in color, so that I can see the different variables better. Does anyone know how to do that. You can see what I mean in this Video at 10:04: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbsI0bNxDEc&list=PLfu_Bpi_zcDNEKmR82hnbv9UxQ16nUBF7&index=95

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It does correct highlighting for me in PhpStorm. I don't think I had to configure anything special.

Comment: You need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with the Database support. See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.